# EntityFieldQuery in a loop

Tags: database

i'm using EntityFieldQuery to retrieve some nodes according to some conditions.

```
foreach (array("important", "normal") as $type) {
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query->entityCondition("entity_type", "node")
    ->entityCondition("bundle", "Announce")
    ->fieldCondition("field_ann_cat", "value", array($nid))
    ->fieldCondition("field_ann_type", "value", array($type));
  $result = $query->execute();
  var_dump($result);
  // Some actions
}
```

The first time it loops, i have my announces marked as "important" (`field_ann_type`).
The second time it loops, i dont have any announces marked as "normal".

I've tried to intervert them, and when i have `array("normal", "important")` instead of `array("important", "normal")` in my foreach, i can see my announces marked as "normal", but not my announces marked as "important".

Does anyone knows why?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use a loop, if you pass an array as the 3rd argument to `fieldCondition` it will create an `IN()` statement for you in MySQL.

As far as I can tell your query should just look like this:

```
$types = array("important", "normal");
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition("entity_type", "node")
  ->entityCondition("bundle", "Announce")
  ->fieldCondition("field_ann_cat", "value", $nid)
  ->fieldCondition("field_ann_type", "value", $types);

$result = $query->execute();
```

If you want to go one step further and ensure the `IN` operator is used you can pass it (but it's not necessary):

```
$query->fieldCondition("field_ann_type", "value", $types, 'IN');
```

As NenadP has already mentioned, there's no need to explicitly use an array as the 3rd argument unless you're putting the value in inline, e.g.

```
$query->fieldCondition("field_ann_type", "value", array("important", "normal"));`
```

Comment: In fact, i wanted them to be in multiple array (what was done in `some actions` commentary). By the way, i found another way to solve my problem. Thanks for the answer, i'll take a look at this later.

Comment: Gotcha. It's quite expensive to put db queries in a loop, if you can get away with grabbing all of the data in one go then using PHP to build up the local structures it's probably advisable

Answer (score 3):

It may be because you are doing this:

```
->fieldCondition("field_ann_type", "value", array($type));
```

try just check it against $type like this:

```
->fieldCondition("field_ann_type", "value", $type);
```

Comment: Thinking about it there's actually no difference at all between those 2 methods...if you wrap the argument in an array the SQL statement will just convert to an `IN()` which is equally valid and will produce exactly the same results.